# eclipse CDT copying all project settings

Tags: export, eclipse-cdt, project-settings

It is possible to export settings from one project and import them in another.

However, it seems that only "include Paths" and "Symbols" can be moved to a new project this way.

Is there any reliable way to copy all settings? Particularly I would like to copy the linker settings for my embedded ARM project.

I do not want copy the settings manually, as this is something that will have to be done often by at bunch of people.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I've discovered to duplicate the settings for a project is to use another workspace. It takes a few steps to set up but you should only need to do it once.
    1. Start a 2nd copy of eclipse and select or create a new workspace.
    2. Import your baseline code.
    3. Rename the project to something generic like NewProject
    4. If your project has files you don't want to be imported into new projects delete them. I find it helpful to keep a few (like main.cpp)

Now back to your original workspace.
1. File->Import->Existing Projects into Workspace `Next` button
2. Use `Browse...` to go to your newly created workspace and select NewProject.
3. Check the `Copy projects into workspace` checkbox.
4. If you have warnings about the project already existing try clicking the `Refresh` button and make sure you don't have a folder in the current workspace with the same name. [ *You can delete a project but not remove it from the hard disk so you have to make sure the intended folder name is not in use.* ]
5. Rename the project to your desired name.
6. Start coding...

All the toolchain settings, include paths and library paths should be intact. It seems like a lot of work, but once you do it once its not too bad (as long as you can keep duplicating that one project).

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in simple steps. Useful if you do not want to create new workspaces.

1. Open the project in the workspace.
2. Click on project and copy.
3. On the project tab area, paste the project.
4. Eclipse asks for a name, rename it to a new project.
5. Click Ok.